# String stream behaves differently to regular stream c++

Tags: c++, string, stream, getline, stringstream

I'm working with string streams for homework task (translating English to 'Piglatin') and have noticed what I think is different behaviour from normal streams, which I don't understand.

The following syntax is what I was taught was 'foolproof' to use for regular streams. But with string streams I sometimes lose the final word in line:

```
stringstream ss(line);
string word;
ss >> word;
while(!ss.eof())
{
  translateWord(word, translated);
  cout << translated;
  if(ss.peek() == ' ')
    cout << ' ';
  ss >> word;
}
```

**line** = but fruit flies like a banana!
**Expected output**: utbay uitfray iesflay ikelay away ananabay!
**Actual output**: utbay uitfray iesflay ikelay away

However, with the following version (not what I've been taught) the final word isn't lost:

```
getline(input, line);
stringstream ss(line);
string word;
while(!ss.eof())
   {
      ss >> word;
      translateWord(word, translated);
      output << translated;
      if(ss.peek() == ' ')
         output << ' ';
   }
```

**line** = but fruit flies like a banana!
**Expected output**: utbay uitfray iesflay ikelay away ananabay!
**Actual output**: utbay uitfray iesflay ikelay away ananabay!

It seems to be to do with the placement of ss >> word .

Can anyone explain this difference? And why string stream behaviour seems to be different from regular streams.

Thanks in advance and sorry if I've missed anything obvious!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. \`while (!stream.eof())\`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons)

Comment: The difference in behavior is very probably because you provided an extra newline to the `cin` version. `>>` stops reading when it encounters whitespace.

Comment: The "canonical" almost foolproof loop is `while (ss >> word)`.